# javascript/nodejs code returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, requestjs

Trying to run this code in nodejs but this returns undefined.
but if i do "console.log(status)" inside de "client.get" function, this shows the right value.
i'm using request-json node package.
i would like a good explanation about, please.

```
    let status;
    client.get(client.host).then((result) => {
      status = result.res.statusCode;
    });

    return status;
```

Comment: put `return status;` inside the then() right below `status = ...`

Comment: JavaScript is executing the last line before `client.get()` has a value.